# Start javascript profiling in IE from js-code

Tags: javascript, profiling, internet-explorer

I want to start and stop js-profiling from my js-code in Internet Explorer.
Like we can do it in Firefox through:
- console.profile()
- console.profileEnd()

Does anybody know whether it is possible in IE?

Answer (score 1):

For JavaScript, XmlHttpRequest, DOM Access, Rendering Times and Network traffic for IE6, 7 & 8 you can use the free [dynaTrace AJAX Edition](http://ajax.dynatrace.com)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Firebug with Firefox, so you could use [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html).

And IE8 has a built-in console, you should read the docs, there are maybe the same functions.